# VS Code beautify break tags in react html

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, js-beautify

I have beautify in VS code, so when I apply it to

```
<div className="chatApp" style={style}>
    <Navigation />
    <ChatField />
</div>
```

I get

```
  <
  div className = "chatApp"
  style = {
    style
  } >
  <
  Navigation / >
  <
  ChatField / >
  <
  /div>
```

but i want somethig like that

```
<div className = "chatApp"
 style = {
     style
 }>
     <Navigation />
     <ChatField />
 </div>
```

Question is how can i change beautify settings to not transfer tags to a new line(div, p, span and etc)?

Comment: Why don't you use something like prettier or eslint?

Comment: prettier is even worse

Comment: didn't know, using it for months and haven't had a single problem. sorry to hear about your pain.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It happened to me as well.
You need to set the language syntax from "plain" javascript to "javascript react".

Look at the images below, you will need to click at the bottom status bar and change the syntax.

[image]

[image]

To update all your files in the project go to "user settings" or "workspace settings" depends if you want it to be set for the project or for your user.

Now look up:

```
  "files.associations": {},
```

and overide it and set something like this:

```
   "files.associations": {
       "*.js": "javascriptreact"
   }
```

Comment: i have tons of files, can i apply it to all files?

Comment: @vboyko if it helped you, please mark it as solved so others could benefit

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue. Below is my finding:
JS-CSS-HTML Formatter extension wraps prettier but it cannot support js files mixed with HTML.
The solution is to disable this extension and enable prettier formatOnSave option for javascript in settings.json as below:

```
"[javascript]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
}
```